# Aggregation with two tables with different amounts of the same key

Tags: sql, count, case, inner-join, aggregate

Other examples can't provide a solution that fits my situation.

Suppose I have two tables Transactions and Budget. Both have the same category names such as 'Mortgage', 'Insurance', 'Car Payment'. However, The Budget Table only has 1 row for each category as a total sum while the Transactions table could have x rows for the matching category. How can I produce a table such that I have for sample parameters @Year = 2016 and @Month = 5:

```
 [Category] [Month to Date Transactions Amount] [Month to Date Budget Amount]
  Mortgage            1000                             1000                           
  Insurance            300                             300
  Car Payment          600                             600
```

Given the following tables:

Transactions

```
 [Transaction_Date]    [Category]    [Amount]
20160504                Mortgage       500
20160524                Mortgage       500
20160510                Insurance      300
20160501                Car Payment    200
20160515                Car Payment    200
20160531                Car Payment    200
```

Budget

```
 [Transaction_Date]    [Category]    [Amount]
20160501                Mortgage       1000
20160501                Insurance      300
20160501                Car Payment    600
```

The Budget Table always uses the 1st day as a default in this case.

When I preform an aggregation with Sum(Case when... ) statements, the [Month to Date Budget Amount] in my query seems to be a factor of the quantity of rows in the Transaction Table. Using SUM(Case when...) statements, I've tried dividing the [Month to Date Budget Amount] column by a COUNT(Case when...) statement but I received "*Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.*" error? Can this be done? My sample code below:

```
 declare @Year as integer = 2016
 Declare @Month as integer = 5

 SELECT
 Transactions.Category
 ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN 
 Year(Transactions.Transaction_Date) = @Year and 
 Month(Transactions.Transaction_Date) = @Month and
 Year(Budget.Transaction_Date) = @Year and
 Month(Budget.Transaction_Date) = @Month
 THEN Transactions.Amount END),0) AS [Month to Date Transactions Amount]
 ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN 
 Year(Transactions.Transaction_Date) = @Year and 
 Month(Transactions.Transaction_Date) = @Month and
 Year(Budget.Transaction_Date) = @Year and
 Month(Budget.Transaction_Date) = @Month
 THEN Budget.Amount END),0) AS [Month to Date Budget Amount]

 FROM
   Transactions
   INNER JOIN Category
     ON Transactions.Category = Budget.Category
 GROUP BY
   Transactions.Category
```

Output

```
      [Category] [Month to Date Transactions Amount] [Month to Date  Budget Amount]
      Mortgage            1000                             2000                           
      Insurance            300                             300
      Car Payment          600                             1800
```

As I've observed, Since there are two mortgage rows in Transactions, we have a double count on the Budget aggregation; likewise with the Car Payment, we have 3 rows and thus the Budget aggregation is triple counted.

Thanks in advance to all who respond.

Comment: Join budget with an aggregation query for transactions.

Answer (score 0):

More than one way of doing this.  Either just switch your second 'SUM' for 'MAX' or, for example, write something like this:

```
declare @Year as integer = 2016
declare @Month as integer = 5

select t.category, t.amount, b.amount
from
  (select category, sum(amount) as amount
  from Transactions
  where year([Transaction_Date]) = @Year
  and month([Transaction_Date]) = @Month
  group by category) t
inner join Budget b
on t.category = b.category
and year(b.[Transaction_Date]) = @Year
and month(b.[Transaction_Date]) = @Month
```

Then add in the required column names.

Alternatively, depending on exactly why you are using variables, you could use:

```
select t.year, t.month, t.category, t.amount as transaction_amount, b.amount as budget_amount
from
  (select year(Transaction_Date) as year, month(Transaction_Date) as month, category, sum(amount) as amount
  from Transactions
  group by year(transaction_date), month(transaction_date), category) t
inner join Budget b
  on t.year = year(b.transaction_date)
  and t.month = month(b.transaction_date)
  and t.category = b.category
-- where t.year = @Year and t.month = @Month
order by t.year, t.month, t.category
```

You can of course restrict the year and month using the where clause and then remove the year and month columns to get back to the original requirement.

**Response to comment:**

```
select t.category, t.amount as transaction_amount, b.amount as budget_amount
from
  (select category, sum(amount) as amount
  from Transactions
  where year([Transaction_Date]) = @Year
  group by category) t
inner join 
  (select category, sum(amount) as amount
  from Budget
  where year([Transaction_Date]) = @Year
  group by category) b
on t.category = b.category
```

Comment: Cool. So Max(Case when...) works for MTD applications. How about YTD given that the YTD Budget amounts are not the same for each month???

Comment: @SQALEX101I've added some code for this at the bottom of my answer.  However, ultimately I think you need to take the time to understand what happens when you join two tables together (without grouping anything), and then what happens when you use GROUP BY on the resultant table.  I would recommend comparing the table before GROUP BY with the table after, and then figuring out what happens when you use SUM, MAX etc.  That should make it clear why I have written the answer I have.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand why you proposed the MAX function for this case. However with nuch trial and tribulation, with both answers, I rewrote the query using two temp tables to uniformly organize the data into a category, MTD, and YTD columns for Budget and Transactions. Then I query/join those tables instead of using "case when" statements. The query has inproved in speed significantly and I get the end result.

Comment: Do you mean the queries didn't work?  It's possible - I have nothing to test them with.  But you should have been able to literally copy and paste them into a query window (with Year and Month variables declared at the top) and run the code.  Glad you got it working, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL below note the use of a begin date for both the current period and the next period. This usage is a standard [*SARG-able*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) pattern ensuring that indices will be used, when available, to optimize disk access; and further that no rtansactions will be either omitted or double-counted if te column type is actually datetime instead of date..

```
declare @Year      as integer   = 2016
      , @Month     as integer   = 5;

declare @thisPdDate as date     = datefromParts(@year,@month,1);
declare @nextPdDate as date     = dateadd(day,1,eomonth(@thisPdDate));

select t.category, t.amount, b.amount
from (
  select category, sum(amount) as amount
  from Transactions
  where @thisPdDate  <= Transaction_Date and Transaction_Date < @nextPdDate
  group by category
) t
inner join Budget b
   on t.category    = b.category
where @thisPdDate  <= b.Transaction_Date and b.Transaction_Date < @nextPdDate
```

These common usages (in either a WHERE or JOIN clause) are *not SARG-able* and will require table scans:

- year(Transaction_Date)
- month(Transaction_Date)

Also, note that the use of BETWEEN ... AND ... for date lookups is an anti-pattern unless one can absolutely guarantee that the column type will be a *date* rather than a *datetime*. If any doubt exists, use the above pattern instead of BETWEEN ... AND ....